# Pipenv: Can't Resolve Dependencies Even with pipenv lock --clear

Tags: python, pipenv

I'm using pipenv version '2018.7.1' along with pip 18.0.

I have a `Pipfile` and run `pipenv install`.

It fails with:
`Could not find a version that matches prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,<2.1.0,==2.0.7,>=1.0.0,>=1.0.4,>=2.0.0
Tried: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.20, 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.25, 0.26, 0.28, 0.30, 0.31, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.37, 0.37, 0.37, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.40, 0.40, 0.40, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.43, 0.43, 0.43, 0.44, 0.44, 0.44, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.46, 0.46, 0.46, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 0.52, 0.52, 0.52, 0.53, 0.53, 0.53, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.56, 0.56, 0.56, 0.57, 0.57, 0.57, 0.58, 0.58, 0.58, 0.59, 0.59, 0.59, 0.60, 0.60, 0.60, 1.0.0, 1.0.0, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.1, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.2, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.3, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.4, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.5, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.6, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.7, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.8, 1.0.8, 1.0.9, 1.0.9, 1.0.9, 1.0.10, 1.0.10, 1.0.10, 1.0.13, 1.0.13, 1.0.13, 1.0.14, 1.0.14, 1.0.14, 1.0.15, 1.0.15, 1.0.15, 2.0.1, 2.0.1, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.2, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.3, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.4, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.5, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.6, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.7, 2.0.7
There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies.`

I check https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/diagnose/ and they suggest trying

`pipenv lock --clear`

and/or clearing the whole cache directory.  I try both, but get the same error as above.  I check out the results of

`pipenv graph`

and see that all of the references to `prompt-toolkit` (the failing dependency) look like:

`- prompt-toolkit [required: >=1.0.4,<2.0.0, installed: 1.0.15]`.

So now I'm super confused since it doesn't seem like there should be a dependency conflict at all.  Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Peilonrayz answer is great if you have overlooked any mentioned dependency. Sometimes, as you mention, `pipenv` doesn't show sub dependencies which do impact resolvability.

Try using `pipenv lock -clear -verbose` and you'll get info about the sub dependencies as well. You can search through them for `'==2.0.7'` (which looks to be your *'missing'* dependency. Once you found the sub dependency which asks for `'==2.0.7'` you can resolve the issue.

Comment: *`pipenv lock --clear --verbose`

Answer (score 0):

It tells you why you can't install.

> Could not find a version that matches `prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,[...],>=2.0.0`

Look in `pipenv graph` again and you should see something like:

> ```
> abc==1.0.1
>   - prompt-toolkit [required: >=1.0.4,<2.0.0, installed: 1.0.15]
> def==1.0.2
>   - prompt-toolkit [required: >=2.0.0, installed: 1.0.15]
> ```

You have to remove one of `abc` or `def`. Or use an older version of `def` that also uses `prompt-toolkit<2.0.0`, if it exists.